# Getting weird console errors/exceptions in eclipse after cucumber test case execution

Tags: eclipse, cucumber, junit5

I have set up my cucumber project and I am using JUnit to run my test cases, but after test case execution/completion getting weird characters in the eclipse console. have attached the image and console error. Is there any workaround for this, please reply.

[image: 1]

Eclipse output:

```
Navigated to page Successfully!!
John
123
Searching for a specific item[enter image description here]
[32m[1m┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐[0m
[32m[1m│[0m Share your Cucumber Report with your team at [36m[1m[4mhttps://reports.cucumber.io[0m          [32m[1m│[0m
[32m[1m│[0m Activate publishing with one of the following:                                    [32m[1m│[0m
[32m[1m│[0m                                                                                   [32m[1m│[0m
[32m[1m│[0m src/test/resources/cucumber.properties:          [36mcucumber.publish.enabled[0m=[36mtrue[0m    [32m[1m│[0m
[32m[1m│[0m src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties:    [36mcucumber.publish.enabled[0m=[36mtrue[0m    [32m[1m│[0m
[32m[1m│[0m Environment variable:                            [36mCUCUMBER_PUBLISH_ENABLED[0m=[36mtrue[0m    [32m[1m│[0m
[32m[1m│[0m JUnit:                                           [36m@CucumberOptions[0m(publish = [36mtrue[0m) [32m[1m│[0m
[32m[1m│[0m                                                                                   [32m[1m│[0m
[32m[1m│[0m More information at [36mhttps://reports.cucumber.io/docs/cucumber-jvm[0m                 [32m[1m│[0m
[32m[1m│[0m                                                                                   [32m[1m│[0m
[32m[1m│[0m Disable this message with one of the following:                                   [32m[1m│[0m
[32m[1m│[0m                                                                                   [32m[1m│[0m
[32m[1m│[0m src/test/resources/cucumber.properties:          [36mcucumber.publish.quiet[0m=[36mtrue[0m      [32m[1m│[0m
[32m[1m│[0m src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties:    [36mcucumber.publish.quiet[0m=[36mtrue[0m      [32m[1m│[0m
[32m[1m└─
```

Comment: It is trying to set the text colours using special sequences in the output text but the Eclipse console does not support that.

Comment: See [ANSI Escape Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)